# Py charm freeze graph not converted 8 variable to constant ops

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

```
import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow.python.tools import freeze_graph,optimize_for_inference_lib

# Saving the graph as a pb file taking data from pbtxt and ckpt files and providing a few operations
freeze_graph.freeze_graph('advanced_mnist.pbtxt',
                          '',
                          True,
                          'advanced_mnist.ckpt',
                          'h_readout1',
                          'save/restore_all',
                          'save/Const:0',
                          'frozen_advance_mnist.pb'
                          ,True,
                          '')
# Read the data form the frozen graph pb file

input_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
with tf.gfile.Open('frozen_advance_mnist.pb','rb') as f:
    data = f.read()
    input_graph_def.ParseFromString(data)
# Optimize the graph with input and output nodes
output_graph_def = optimize_for_inference_lib.optimize_for_inference(input_graph_def,['x_input','keep_prob'],['h_readout1'],tf.float32.as_datatype_enum)
# Save the optimized graph to the optimized pb file
f = tf.gfile.FastGFile('optimized_advanced_mnist.pb','w')
f.write(output_graph_def.SerializeToString())
```

I try run the input and output but the file not convert the variables into any constant ops instead just process finished with exit code 0.

Comment: Welcome to SO. If you are asking a question about an error or code, it needs to be in there as text otherwise it won't be searchable for other users. Images are useful in a post, but make sure the post is still clear without them. If you post images of code or error messages, copy and paste or type the actual code or message into the post directly.

Comment: i get what are you saying.

Comment: @IsnizalZuhri: Do you plan to improve your question?

Comment: yes, I am so sorry late reply